# Initialize array of a class with fixed length and dynamically add values in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, instantiation

I want to have a two-dimensional game board, and every field is a custom class with information about this field, with properties. The size of the game board is known on instantiation, the values of the properties are not. After instantiation, I want to randomly set them for each field. My initial idea was to create an array, not a list, because the size of the game board is always fixed.

```
public class GameBoard
{
    private int _xValue;
    private int _yValue;
    private int _bombs;

    private int _fields;

    public Field[][] gameBoard;

    public GameBoard(int x, int y)
    {
        _xValue = x;
        _yValue = y;
        _fields = _xValue * _yValue;

        gameBoard = new[] { new Field[_xValue], new Field[_yValue] };
    //Here I have to initialize every Field

        for (int i = 0; i < _xValue; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _yValue; j++)
            {
                //Set properties of Field
                //For example: gameBoard[i][j].IsBomb = RandomBoolean;
                //Here I get NullReferenceExceptions
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do understand why this does not work. I tried lists, two-dimensional arrays or, like at the moment, a jagged array, what I would prefer. How can I solve this problem in a readable, clean way?

**EDIT**

The Field class:

```
public class Field
{
    public bool IsBomb { get; set; }
    public bool IsFlagged { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to add `gameBoard[i][j] = new Field();` inside the nested forloop. This leads to an IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: Since `Field` is a `class` then after `gameBoard = new[] { new Field[_xValue], new Field[_yValue] };` you have a jagged array of `null`s - you need to `new` them in your loop

Comment: Yes, Field is a class, I will edit my question. I tried `gameBoard[i][j] = new Field();`, in the nested for loop. Then I get: IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: can you add your Field class ?

Comment: You can use a `List` and convert it to `Array` after adding an items

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Why would you use a `List` at all? There is no need.

Comment: @Josh you can add values without knowing an intial size. Another option is to use `Array.Resize`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski `The size of the game board is known on instantiation`, knowing the initial size isn't the problem. The problem is that OP never actually specifies what that size is supposed to be, so he just created an empty jagged array.

Comment: Well, the problem here is just a proper initialization of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of confusion in here on how to work with jagged arrays. If you want to work with jagged arrays, you have to setup in such a way

```
//Declare jagged array, I want _xValue arrays
Field[][] gameBoard = new Field[_xValue][];

for (int i = 0; i < _xValue; i++)
{
    gameBoard[i] = new Field[_yValue];
    for (int j = 0; j < _yValue; j++)
    {
        gameBoard[i][j] = new Field(){ IsBomb = RandomBoolean};
    }
}
```

The equivalent in a multi-dimensional array would be

```
//Declare multi-dimensional array of size _xValue x _yValue
Field[,] gameBoard2 = new Field[_xValue, _yValue];

for(int i = 0; i < _xValue; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < _yValue; j++)
    {
        // Instantiate the Field object at x,y
        gameBoard2[i, j] = new Field { IsBomb = RandomBoolean };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your array-property:

```
public Field[,] gameBoard;
```

And here is initialization:

```
public GameBoard(int x, int y)
{
    _xValue = x;
    _yValue = y;
    _fields = _xValue * _yValue;

    gameBoard = new Field[_xValue, _yValue];
    for (int i = 0; i < _xValue; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < _yValue; j++)
        {
            gameBoard[i, j] = new Field();
        }
    }
 }
```